# Bug: Inline code highlighting in comments encloses trailing space

Tags: bug

Have a look at [these comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25097/3168) containing some inline code.

The highlighting of the inline code incorrectly encloses the normal text space after the trailing `.

This seems to be some mistake in the CSS definition.

Comment: Almost there! I have got now `onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') == 1 ? ":<C-U>normal! lvt$<CR>" : ":<C-U>normal! hET$v,<CR>"` and I am wondering whether one can extend the test for the character under the cursor at the beginning of the line; i.e. something like `== 1 && char(col(':')) == "$"` I find it hard to find the pertaining documentation for these tests.

Comment: As shown above, **I cannot reproduce the bug here in Meta.**

Comment: The weird thing is, it does not work at the beginning of the line with the almost identical mapping `onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') == 1 ? "f$" : ":<C-U>normal! hEF$lv,h<CR>"
` Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: ^^ That's same text of your comment from that answer. It looks like there's a newline character there just before the last `.

Comment: The weird thing is, it does not work at the beginning of the line with the almost identical mapping `onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') == 1 ? "f$" : ":<C-U>normal! hEF$lv,h<CR>"` Help would be much appreciated! (Removed newline character.)

Comment: @filbranden Cleverly seen! That newline must have slipped in when copying the code. Evidently, Vim scripting is driving me crazy! ;-)

Comment: The odd thing is that after removing the newline character I still see the same...

Comment: @filbranden The other thing I did notice is that ` == 1 && char(col(':')) == "$"` does not work when ` is immediately followed by a space. However, that could be a Markdown thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## TL;DR backticks are always weird

But this is the type of thing that should be discussed on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com), not here. We can't change the markdown processing here. Only SE can do that, and they need to know about it. (That said, I suspect a search on meta.SE will turn up *many* results on this.)

---

As filbranden and I independently noticed, there *is* extra whitespace within the backticks:

```
The weird thing is, it does not work at the beginning of the line with the almost identical mapping `onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') == 1 ? "f$" : ":<C-U>normal! hEF$lv,h<CR>"
` Help would be much appreciated!
```

```
Almost there! I have got now `onoremap <expr> i$ col('.') == 1 ? ":<C-U>normal! lvt$<CR>" : ":<C-U>normal! hET$v,<CR>"
` and I am wondering whether one can extend the test for the character under the cursor at the beginning of the line; i.e. something like ` == 1 && char(col(':')) == "$"` I find it hard to find the pertaining documentation for these tests.
```

In both cases it's a newline that causes this problem.

### Other experiments

And yes, following a backtick with a space ` causes it to appear on its own.

However,  `<here is one and here's another>` with the same spacing renders...

And trying to get a backtick in code formatting: ``` is atrocious. ``` with a \ escape doesn't work either. And it always messes up formatting for the rest of the paragraph...

`<code>` tags and `<pre>` tags work the best:

This is a backtick: `` ` `` but it still messes up if there's more than one:

Backtick `</code> backtick <code>`.

Rich pointed out [even more tricks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82718/389795)

Comment: <code>tags</code> and <pre>tags</pre> don't work in comments, though

Comment: [This meta.se question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-within-in-line-code-in-markdown?rq=1) contains lots of tricks for getting around the deficiencies in backtick processing in various different contexts. (Noting more for my future reference than anything else.)